# How to display an image in Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm working on a simple augmented reality application, taking data from a web camera and presenting it to the user. While I've already gotten access to the bits coming out of the web camera, I don't have any idea how to present pictures in C++ Qt3D. While there are examples of loading a picture in QML, there's nothing in C++.

Can anyone show me a simple minimal example of loading a picture into a texture buffer and binding it to tex0 using the C++ Qt3D framework?

Comment: Map a [QTextureImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3drender-qtextureimage.html) to a rectangle: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-materials-cpp-example.html

Comment: Or if you need it as a background image: https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/Qt3D-BackgroundImage

Comment: @HappyFeet Nice! That's close enough to get started. I'll post the final code here for the community once I'm done.

Comment: @BenHoff did you manage to get some code working? You could concertize your question a bit and pose an answer - maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: I never did, no. Ended up rescoping completely because it was easier